# Problem 3 in section 3.3 from Velleman's "How to prove it"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am currently stuck on Exercise 3 from section 3.3 in Velleman's "How to prove it".
I was sort of able to manipulate the statements but I think a final subtle step is missing in my proof. Here is what I have got so far:
We are supposed to prove:
$$A\subseteq B/C \rightarrow A\cap C=\emptyset$$
The consequent can be manipulated to give:
$$\lnot \exists x(x\in A\,\land\,x\in C)$$
Which is logically equivalent to:
$$\forall x(\lnot (x\in A)\,\lor\,\lnot (x\in C))$$
The antecedent can be manipulated to give:
$$x\in A \rightarrow x\in B \land \lnot(x\in C)$$
I am not sure how to proceed from here. I tried using the logical equivalent of the conditional, but that didn't help matters much.

Comment: Try using the strategies introduced in Section 3.3 of the book.  Since you have written the goal in the form $\forall x(\ldots)$, try starting with "Let $x$ be arbitrary".

Comment: By the way, the antecedent is $\forall x(x \in A \to x \in B \wedge \neg(x \in C))$.

Comment: Alternatively, since your first version of the goal was a negative statement, you could use proof by contradiction.  Assume $\exists x(x \in A \wedge x \in C)$.  Then, again using strategies introduced in Section 3.3, you can introduce some object $x_0$ such that $x_0 \in A \wedge x_0 \in C$.  Now you need to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Looks like the OP is getting some expert advice :P

Comment: @DanVelleman I am so honored that you are giving me a hint. I will give it a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Scroll down to see simpler proof.
Ok, I think I got it now:
We begin by stating the givens and the goals:

Given:
$$A\subseteq B/C$$
Goal:
$$A\cap C=\emptyset$$

We can write the given as:

$$\forall x (x\in A \rightarrow x\in B \land x\notin C)$$
Now using the logical equivalent of the conditional this can be simplified:
$$\forall x (x\notin A \lor (x\in B \land x\notin C))$$
Then using the distributivity property and De Morgan's Theorem:
$$\forall x ((x\notin A \lor x\in B) \land \lnot (x\in A \land x\in C))$$
At the same time we can also write the goal as:
$$\nexists x (x\in A \land x\in C)$$
Therefore if we assume the negated Goal then this entails a contradiction with the given because $$\lnot (x\in A \land x\in C))$$ has to be true.

Edit:
Here is the simpler proof from the solution at the back of the book:
We start by assuming that $A\subseteq B/C$ and $A$ and $C$ not being disjoint.
That means we can choose an $x$ such that it is both in $A$ and $C$. Since $x$ is in $A$ by the first assumption and the definition of a subset $x$ is in B and not in $C$. But we have assumed that $x$ is both in $A$ and $C$. This is a contradiction and we are done since the assumption must be false.

Comment: This is the right idea, but I still think the proof would be simpler if you _use the strategies in the book_.  Translating your symbols back into English, your reasoning is "for every $x$, if $x \in A$ then ...," and therefore "for every $x$, either $x \notin A$ or ...," and therefore "for every $x$, ..."  There is no need to reason about _all_ $x$s.  Start with "assume $\exists x(x \in A \wedge x \in C)$.  Then immediately say you can choose some $x$ such that $x \in A \wedge x \in C$.  Now reason about that _one_ $x$, not all $x$s.

Comment: By the way, there is a solution in the back of the book for this one.  The solution is along the lines of my comment above.

Comment: @DanVelleman Thanks. I hadn't checked the solution in the book. But yes that is a much simpler proof.